# Relation between centre of mass and axis of rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Why is that in absence of a manually fixed point, a body shows its turning effect on application of a torque with its axis of rotation through its centre of mass?
my attempt:
is there a definition of the centre of mass that im mising?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81029/

Comment: In short: no, you can think that it rotates around ANY point you choose. However, choosing the CoM makes the SIMPLEST description.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/cm.html

Comment: Please [read this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80449/392) to a similar question as I think it will steer you in the right direction.

Comment: See also [Rotation and center of mass -- A collection of common doubts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410700) and the many similar questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The two properties of the center of mass are related (actually a result of the definition of center of mass).

1. A force (or impulse) acting through the center of mass purely translates a rigid body.
2. A pure torque (or lack of force) acting on a body will rotate the body about the center of mass.

### It all starts with momentum.

Treat the rigid body as a system of particles which maintain all distances between them. The only motions allowed are either pure translation, rotation about an arbitrary axis, or a combination of the two.

> The location in space (which I note as *C*) whose linear velocity can be used to describe the total linear momentum of a group of particles is called the *center of mass*:
>    $$ \vec{p} = \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_i = \vec{v}_C\, (\sum_i m_i) $$
>
> Additionally, the net force acting on a body (regardless of the point of application) equals the time derivative of momentum
>    $$ \vec{F} = \sum_i \vec{F}_i = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{p} = \vec{a}_C\,  (\sum_i m_i)$$

What this tells you is that the forces acting on a body **only describe the motion of the center of mass**. As a consequence the lack of a net force requires that the center of mass either doesn't move, or moves with constant velocity $$ \sum_i \vec{F}_i =0 \Rightarrow \vec{a}_C =0 $$

### And angular momentum

> It turns out that if you calculate the total angular momentum of the system of particles *about the center of mass* the results don't depend on the motion of the center of mass, but only on the rotational velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ of the rigid body.
>    $$ \vec{L}_C = \sum_i (\vec{r}_i - \vec{r}_C) \times \vec{v}_i = \mathrm{I}_C\, \vec{\omega} $$
>
> Additionally, the total torque applied on a rigid body equals the rate of the change of angular momentum *at the center of mass*.
>    $$ \vec{\tau}_C = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{L}_C = \mathrm{I}_C \vec{\alpha} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{L}_C $$

What this tells you is that the torques acting on a rigid body **only describe the rotational motion of the body about the center of mass**.

### Summary

The center of a mass is a special point in on the body which decouples the evaluation of momemtum from the motion.

> - The linear momentum of rigid body equals the mass times the linear velocity *of the center of mass* (regardless of rotation). $$ \vec{p} = m \vec{v}_C $$
> - The angular momentum of a rigid body equals the mass moment of inertia (tensor) times the rotational velocity (regardless of translation). $$ \vec{L}_C = \mathrm{I}_C \vec{\omega} $$

Any other point of evaluation would result in cross dependent components of the above evaluations [as seen here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/314338/392).